# Daemon does not write to file

Tags: c, logging, daemon

I wrote a daemon that is supposed to log itself when it recieves a signal. If I do not daemonize the process, it works correctly and writes to the file and I can see all the signals it recieved. But when I daemonize it, and send a signal for ex `kill -14 (pid)` , the daemon never writes to the file that the signal is recieved. Code is below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "signalinfo.h"
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <syslog.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

char *newline = "\n ";

void
daemonize(const char *cmd)
{
    int i, fd0, fd1, fd2;
    pid_t  pid;
    struct rlimit rl;
    struct sigaction    sa;

    umask(0);

    if (getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, &rl) < 0) {
        printf("Can't get file limit\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
        printf("Can't Fork\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if (pid != 0) /* parent */
        exit(0);
    setsid();

    sa.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;
sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = 0;
    if (sigaction(SIGHUP, &sa, NULL) < 0){
        printf("Can't ignore SIGHUP\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
        printf("Can't Fork\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    else if (pid != 0) /* parent */
        exit(0);

    if (chdir("/") < 0) {
        printf("Can't Change Directory to /\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

    if (rl.rlim_max == RLIM_INFINITY)
        rl.rlim_max = 1024;
    for (i = 0; i < rl.rlim_max; i++)
        close(i);

    fd0 = open("/dev/null", O_RDWR);
    fd1 = dup(0);
    fd2 = dup(0);

    openlog(cmd, LOG_CONS, LOG_DAEMON);
    if (fd0 != 0 || fd1 != 1 || fd2 != 2) {
        syslog(LOG_ERR, "unexpected file descriptors %d %d %d",
          fd0, fd1, fd2);
        exit(1);
    }
}

void 
setsig(struct sigaction sa)
{
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<SIGNAL_LIST_LENGTH; i++) {
        printf("%d Set\n", siglist[i].code);
        if(sigaction(siglist[i].code, &sa, NULL) == -1) { //Will error     on SIGSTOP & SIGKILL
        }           
    }
}

void 
handler(int sig)
{
    char path[PATH_MAX];
    int fd, flags, i;

    flags = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IWOTH | S_IROTH;
    getcwd(path, PATH_MAX);
    strcat(path,"/signal.log");
    fd = open(path, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_APPEND | O_NONBLOCK , flags);

    for(i=0; i<SIGNAL_LIST_LENGTH; i++) {
        if(sig == siglist[i].code) {
            write(fd, siglist[i].name, strlen(siglist[i].name));
            write(fd, newline, strlen(newline));
        }
    }

    close(fd);
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    char *cmd;
    struct sigaction sa;
    sa.sa_handler = handler;


    setsig(sa);

    if((cmd = strchr(argv[0], '/')) == NULL)
        cmd = argv[0];
    else
        cmd++;
    daemonize(cmd);

    while(1) {
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Any Idea as to why I can't write to the file that I created? It works correctly when I dont daemonize it but when I do, it doesn't work.

Comment: maybe `fd == -1` ?

Comment: You're trying to write to the root directory:  `chdir("/")`

Comment: should I just write it to my home directory? So maybe `chdir("/home/md")` ? I am not sure as to why you couldn't log to root.

Comment: Are you running the process as `root`?  Any process with permission to write to the root directory effectively has complete control of everything on the machine.